# Android Intellij edit Gradle tasks

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

How to edit those Gradle tasks or create my new Gradle tasks. I have googled but cannot find enough information.

[image: Gradle Tasks]

These are Gradle Tasks, I want to create here new Gradle Tasks or is there any way I can edit (change code) and see code of these tasks?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking about.

Comment: @Opal I want to edit those tasks or at least add my own Gradle task. like after install debug it can launch my main activity by getting name from manifest file.

Comment: What does it mean *to edit those tasks*?

Comment: I want to make changes in the code of those tasks

Comment: To add a new task you need to put it in an appropriate gradle script: typically `build.gradle`. The question is not precise enough to give a good answer :|

Comment: Can you please refer me to some good basic tutorial regarding Gradle wrapper and things like that I have read about it but it's in so much detail. it's like a complete book :-/

Comment: Trust me, there's no better site to start with gradle: http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html